Adding azure strorage container to strapi v5
I have added a storage container to azure and I need to implement in strapi. If I do the following my app deploys fine but files dont use the blob storage then the plugin.ts look as follows:
"use strict";
Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
exports.default = () => ({});

Then trying to add blob storage I add to plugin.ts:
module.exports = ({ env }) => ({
  upload: {
    config: {
      provider: "strapi-provider-upload-azure-storage",
      providerOptions: {
        authType: env("STORAGE_AUTH_TYPE", "default"),
        account: env("STORAGE_ACCOUNT"),
        accountKey: env("STORAGE_ACCOUNT_KEY"),//either account key or sas token is enough to make authentication 
        containerName: env("STORAGE_CONTAINER_NAME"),
        defaultPath: "assets",
      },
    },
  },
});

The issue is if I deploy the code then once deployed it errors out when going to upload a photo with "An error occurred while uploading the file."
